# Two corollaries to a fact about rational maps from nonsingular varieties to projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm looking at the material in Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry I".

> Theorem: If $ X $ is a nonsingular variety and $ \varphi : X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^{n} $ a rational map to projective space, then the set of points at which $ \varphi $ is not regular has codimension $ \geq 2. $

There are two corollaries to this theorem stated in the text. I'm having trouble understanding why they follow from the theorem.

> Corollary 1: Any rational map of a nonsingular curve to projective space is regular.

I feel silly for being confused about this one, but I'm not seeing directly how the theorem implies this.

> Corollary 2: If two nonsingular projective curves are birational then they are isomorphic.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is a codimension 2 set in a curve?

Comment: @Mohan the empty set?

Comment: Good, doesn't it make the proofs for the corollaries clear?

Comment: @Mohan It does. I'm an idiot. Thank you